# Access WCF service through internet?

Tags: wcf

**
Hi all,
I develop a wcf service which works in several pc connected with a network, i want to to make all clients connect to the server through internet, how can it be done?

thanks in advance.
**

Comment: Any feedback on the solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio -> File -> New Project -> Web -> ASP.NET Web application

After you create the Project, add a Web Service (WCF)

Answer (score 0):

If you need some help in setting up RESTful web services using WCF the WCF-REST starter kit (http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/wcf-rest/) might help.

> The WCF REST Starter Kit is a set of
>   .Net Framework classes and Visual
>   Studio features and templates that
>   enable users to create and access
>   REST-style Windows Communication
>   Foundation (WCF) services. These
>   services are based on the WCF web
>   programming model available in .Net
>   3.5 SP1. The starter kit also contains the full source code for all features,
>   detailed code samples, and unit tests.